# Git clone is failing with error code 503 while using LibGit2sharp library

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am unable to clone git repo using libgit2sharp library. I am trying to clone from a remote git repo and that repo is accessible through browser always, however through the program I am getting 503 error when connected to LAN/WIFI office network and works fine when connected to VPN network. Also same program works well in another PC while connected to same LAN/WIFI/VPN networks.

In my PC where the program doesnt work in LAN/Wifi network,I tried cloning the repo using git bash, using jgit library - both ways I am able to clone but using libgit2sharp its failing. I checked proxy settings but couldnt find any. If its related to a network, then the issue should be consistent across all PC's and if the issue is related to a PC configuration then in all the networks git clone should fail. I am unable to figure it out the cause.

Please let me know if I am missing something

**Update**

We identified the issue to be winhttp proxy setting. Libgit2sharp uses winhttp proxy and doesnot honour internet proxy settings.Is there a way to change this behaviour - use internet proxy settings rather than winhttp proxy settings.